# Add Items in BrowseFragment Header in Android TV

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I have used Google sample project of android tv leanback library as a reference.

So, my question is how to add items (i.e. Button, ImageView, TextView) along with search button in BrowseFragment Header in Android TV.

I can able to hide search button using commenting below code, but I can not able to add items along with search button.

```
    setOnSearchClickedListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SearchActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: have you found any better solution for this?

Comment: @abhishek Actually i did tried many ideas to customize it but none of the worked. And lastly i haven't check on this for so long.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but I think, You need to Customize **Browse Fragment**. 
    You can extend **Browse Fragment** in a java class and then try to customize 
    it or try to make it invisible. You can Customize **Row Fragment** and **Header Fragment** and create a custom **Frame layout**.

**activity_main.xml**

```
   <android.support.v17.leanback.widget.SearchOrbView
        android:id="@+id/custom_search_orb"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
       android:visibility="gone"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/header_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/rows_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:layout_marginLeft="300dp" />

</com.ttnd.androidtv.views.CustomFrameLayout>`
```

**CustomRowFragment.java**

```
    import android.app.LoaderManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.Loader;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.app.RowsFragment;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ArrayObjectAdapter;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HeaderItem;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ImageCardView;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ListRow;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ListRowPresenter;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.OnItemViewClickedListener;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Presenter;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Row;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowPresenter;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActivityOptionsCompat;
    import android.telecom.Connection;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import com.Utils;
    import com.example.ttnd.demoapptv.R;
    import com.ttnd.androidtv.models.Movie;
    import com.ttnd.androidtv.presenter.CardPresenter;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Random;


    public class CustomRowsFragment extends RowsFragment {

        private ArrayObjectAdapter rowsAdapter;

        private static String mVideosUrl;

        // CustomHeadersFragment, scaled by 0.9 on a 1080p screen, is 600px wide.
        // This is the corresponding dip size.
        private static final int HEADERS_FRAGMENT_SCALE_SIZE = 300;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

            int marginOffset = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, HEADERS_FRAGMENT_SCALE_SIZE, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            params.rightMargin -= marginOffset;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);


            rowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
            CardPresenter cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
                ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);

                    listRowAdapter.add(new Movie());

                HeaderItem header = new HeaderItem(0, "01234");

                rowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));

            setAdapter(rowsAdapter);

            //v.setBackgroundColor(getRandomColor());
            return v;
        }



        private void loadVideoData() {

        }


        private int getRandomColor() {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
        }

        public void refresh() {
            getView().setPadding(Utils.convertDpToPixel(getActivity(), -24), Utils.convertDpToPixel(getActivity(), 128), Utils.convertDpToPixel(getActivity(), 300), 0);
        }

    }
```

**CustomHeaderFragment.java**

```
   package android.support.v17.leanback.app;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.R;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.FocusHighlightHelper;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ItemBridgeAdapter;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.PresenterSelector;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.OnItemViewSelectedListener;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Row;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.RowHeaderPresenter;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.SinglePresenterSelector;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.util.TypedValue;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.View.OnLayoutChangeListener;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    public class HeadersFragment extends BaseRowFragment {

        interface OnHeaderClickedListener {
            void onHeaderClicked();
        }

        interface OnHeaderViewSelectedListener {
            void onHeaderSelected(RowHeaderPresenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Row row);
        }

        private OnHeaderViewSelectedListener mOnHeaderViewSelectedListener;
        private OnHeaderClickedListener mOnHeaderClickedListener;
        private boolean mHeadersEnabled = true;
        private boolean mHeadersGone = false;
        private int mBackgroundColor;
        private boolean mBackgroundColorSet;

        private static final PresenterSelector sHeaderPresenter = new SinglePresenterSelector(
                new RowHeaderPresenter(R.layout.lb_header));

        public HeadersFragment() {
            setPresenterSelector(sHeaderPresenter);
        }

        public void setOnHeaderClickedListener(OnHeaderClickedListener listener) {
            mOnHeaderClickedListener = listener;
        }

        public void setOnHeaderViewSelectedListener(OnHeaderViewSelectedListener listener) {
            mOnHeaderViewSelectedListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        VerticalGridView findGridViewFromRoot(View view) {
            return (VerticalGridView) view.findViewById(R.id.browse_headers);
        }

        @Override
        void onRowSelected(RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                int position, int subposition) {
            if (mOnHeaderViewSelectedListener != null) {
                if (viewHolder != null && position >= 0) {
                    Row row = (Row) getAdapter().get(position);
                    ItemBridgeAdapter.ViewHolder vh = (ItemBridgeAdapter.ViewHolder) viewHolder;
                    mOnHeaderViewSelectedListener.onHeaderSelected(
                            (RowHeaderPresenter.ViewHolder) vh.getViewHolder(), row);
                } else {
                    mOnHeaderViewSelectedListener.onHeaderSelected(null, null);
                }
            }
        }

        private final ItemBridgeAdapter.AdapterListener mAdapterListener =
                new ItemBridgeAdapter.AdapterListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCreate(ItemBridgeAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
                View headerView = viewHolder.getViewHolder().view;
                headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if (mOnHeaderClickedListener != null) {
                            mOnHeaderClickedListener.onHeaderClicked();
                        }
                    }
                });
                headerView.setFocusable(true);
                headerView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                if (mWrapper != null) {
                    viewHolder.itemView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(sLayoutChangeListener);
                } else {
                    headerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(sLayoutChangeListener);
                }
            }

        };

        private static OnLayoutChangeListener sLayoutChangeListener = new OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom,
                int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                v.setPivotX(v.getLayoutDirection() == View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL ? v.getWidth() : 0);
                v.setPivotY(v.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
            }
        };

        @Override
        int getLayoutResourceId() {
            return R.layout.lb_headers_fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
            final VerticalGridView listView = getVerticalGridView();
            if (listView == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (getBridgeAdapter() != null) {
                FocusHighlightHelper.setupHeaderItemFocusHighlight(listView);
            }
            view.setBackgroundColor(getBackgroundColor());
            updateFadingEdgeToBrandColor(getBackgroundColor());
            updateListViewVisibility();
        }

        private void updateListViewVisibility() {
            final VerticalGridView listView = getVerticalGridView();
            if (listView != null) {
                getView().setVisibility(mHeadersGone ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                if (!mHeadersGone) {
                    if (mHeadersEnabled) {
                        listView.setChildrenVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        listView.setChildrenVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void setHeadersEnabled(boolean enabled) {
            mHeadersEnabled = enabled;
            updateListViewVisibility();
        }

        void setHeadersGone(boolean gone) {
            mHeadersGone = gone;
            updateListViewVisibility();
        }

        static class NoOverlappingFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

            public NoOverlappingFrameLayout(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasOverlappingRendering() {
                return false;
            }
        }


        private final ItemBridgeAdapter.Wrapper mWrapper = new ItemBridgeAdapter.Wrapper() {
            @Override
            public void wrap(View wrapper, View wrapped) {
                ((FrameLayout) wrapper).addView(wrapped);
            }

            @Override
            public View createWrapper(View root) {
                return new NoOverlappingFrameLayout(root.getContext());
            }
        };
        @Override
        void updateAdapter() {
            super.updateAdapter();
            ItemBridgeAdapter adapter = getBridgeAdapter();
            if (adapter != null) {
                adapter.setAdapterListener(mAdapterListener);
                adapter.setWrapper(mWrapper);
            }
            if (adapter != null && getVerticalGridView() != null) {
                FocusHighlightHelper.setupHeaderItemFocusHighlight(getVerticalGridView());
            }
        }

        void setBackgroundColor(int color) {
            mBackgroundColor = color;
            mBackgroundColorSet = true;

            if (getView() != null) {
                getView().setBackgroundColor(mBackgroundColor);
                updateFadingEdgeToBrandColor(mBackgroundColor);
            }
        }

        private void updateFadingEdgeToBrandColor(int backgroundColor) {
            View fadingView = getView().findViewById(R.id.fade_out_edge);
            Drawable background = fadingView.getBackground();
            if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
                background.mutate();
                ((GradientDrawable) background).setColors(
                        new int[] {Color.TRANSPARENT, backgroundColor});
            }
        }

        int getBackgroundColor() {
            if (getActivity() == null) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must be attached");
            }

            if (mBackgroundColorSet) {
                return mBackgroundColor;
            }

            TypedValue outValue = new TypedValue();
            if (getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.defaultBrandColor, outValue, true)) {
                return getResources().getColor(outValue.resourceId);
            }
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.lb_default_brand_color);
        }

        @Override
        void onTransitionStart() {
            super.onTransitionStart();
            if (!mHeadersEnabled) {

                final VerticalGridView listView = getVerticalGridView();
                if (listView != null) {
                    listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BEFORE_DESCENDANTS);
                    if (listView.hasFocus()) {
                        listView.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        void onTransitionEnd() {
            if (mHeadersEnabled) {
                final VerticalGridView listView = getVerticalGridView();
                if (listView != null) {
                    listView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
                    if (listView.hasFocus()) {
                        listView.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }
            super.onTransitionEnd();
        }
    }
```

**CustomFrameLayout.java**

```
     package com.ttnd.androidtv.views;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Rect;
    import android.util.AttributeSet;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    public class CustomFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {

        public interface OnFocusSearchListener {
            View onFocusSearch(View focused, int direction);
        }

        public interface OnChildFocusListener {
            boolean onRequestFocusInDescendants(int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect);
            void onRequestChildFocus(View child, View focused);
        }

        public CustomFrameLayout(Context context) {
            this(context, null, 0);
        }

        public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            this(context, attrs, 0);
        }

        public CustomFrameLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        }

        private OnFocusSearchListener mListener;
        private OnChildFocusListener mOnChildFocusListener;

        public void setOnFocusSearchListener(OnFocusSearchListener listener) {
            mListener = listener;
        }

        public void setOnChildFocusListener(OnChildFocusListener listener) {
            mOnChildFocusListener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onRequestFocusInDescendants(int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
            if (mOnChildFocusListener != null) {
                return mOnChildFocusListener.onRequestFocusInDescendants(direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
            }
            return super.onRequestFocusInDescendants(direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
        }

        @Override
        public View focusSearch(View focused, int direction) {
            if (mListener != null) {
                View view = mListener.onFocusSearch(focused, direction);
                if (view != null) {
                    return view;
                }
            }
            return super.focusSearch(focused, direction);
        }

        @Override
        public void requestChildFocus(View child, View focused) {
            super.requestChildFocus(child, focused);
            if (mOnChildFocusListener != null) {
                mOnChildFocusListener.onRequestChildFocus(child, focused);
            }
        }
    }
```

**CardPresenter.java**

```
     package com.ttnd.androidtv.presenter;

    import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.ImageCardView;
    import android.support.v17.leanback.widget.Presenter;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
    import com.example.ttnd.demoapptv.R;
    import com.ttnd.androidtv.models.Movie;


    public class CardPresenter extends Presenter {
        private static final String TAG = "CardPresenter";

        private static int CARD_WIDTH = 313;
        private static int CARD_HEIGHT = 176;
        private static int sSelectedBackgroundColor;
        private static int sDefaultBackgroundColor;
        private Drawable mDefaultCardImage;

        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");

            sDefaultBackgroundColor = parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.default_background);
            sSelectedBackgroundColor = parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.selected_background);
            mDefaultCardImage = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

            ImageCardView cardView = new ImageCardView(parent.getContext()) {
                @Override
                public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                    updateCardBackgroundColor(this, selected);
                    super.setSelected(selected);
                }
            };

            cardView.setFocusable(true);
            cardView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            updateCardBackgroundColor(cardView, false);
            return new ViewHolder(cardView);
        }

        private static void updateCardBackgroundColor(ImageCardView view, boolean selected) {
            int color = selected ? sSelectedBackgroundColor : sDefaultBackgroundColor;

            view.setBackgroundColor(color);
            view.findViewById(R.id.info_field).setBackgroundColor(color);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object item) {
            Movie movie = (Movie) item;
            ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;

            Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder");
            if (movie.getCardImageUrl() != null) {
                cardView.setTitleText(movie.getTitle());
                cardView.setContentText(movie.getStudio());
                cardView.setMainImageDimensions(CARD_WIDTH, CARD_HEIGHT);
                Glide.with(viewHolder.view.getContext())
                        .load(movie.getCardImageUrl())
                        .centerCrop()
                        .error(mDefaultCardImage)
                        .into(cardView.getMainImageView());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUnbindViewHolder(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onUnbindViewHolder");
            ImageCardView cardView = (ImageCardView) viewHolder.view;

            cardView.setBadgeImage(null);
            cardView.setMainImage(null);
        }
    }
```

**Movie.java**

```
     package com.ttnd.androidtv.models;

    import android.os.Parcel;
    import android.os.Parcelable;

    import java.net.URI;
    import java.net.URISyntaxException;


    public class Movie implements Parcelable {
        private static final String TAG = "Movie";
        static final long serialVersionUID = 727566175075960653L;
        private static int sCount = 0;
        private String mId = "0";
        private String mTitle = "Title Here";
        private String mDescription = "Description Here";
        private String mBgImageUrl = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/android-tv/Sample%20videos/Demo%20Slam/Google%20Demo%20Slam_%2020ft%20Search/bg.jpg";
        private String mCardImageUrl = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/android-tv/Sample%20videos/Zeitgeist/Zeitgeist%202010_%20Year%20in%20Review/card.jpg";
        private String mVideoUrl = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4";
        private String mStudio = "Studio Here";
        private String mCategory = "Category Here";

        public Movie() {

        }

        public Movie(Parcel in){
            String[] data = new String[8];

            in.readStringArray(data);
            mId = data[0];
            mTitle = data[1];
            mDescription = data[2];
            mBgImageUrl = data[3];
            mCardImageUrl = data[4];
            mVideoUrl = data[5];
            mStudio = data[6];
            mCategory = data[7];
        }

        public static String getCount() {
            return Integer.toString(sCount);
        }

        public static void incrementCount() {
            sCount++;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return mId;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
            mId = id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return mTitle;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            mTitle = title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return mDescription;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            mDescription = description;
        }

        public String getStudio() {
            return mStudio;
        }

        public void setStudio(String studio) {
            mStudio = studio;
        }

        public String getVideoUrl() {
            return mVideoUrl;
        }

        public void setVideoUrl(String videoUrl) {
            mVideoUrl = videoUrl;
        }

        public String getBackgroundImageUrl() {
            return mBgImageUrl;
        }

        public void setBackgroundImageUrl(String bgImageUrl) {
            mBgImageUrl = bgImageUrl;
        }

        public String getCardImageUrl() {
            return mCardImageUrl;
        }

        public void setCardImageUrl(String cardImageUrl) {
            mCardImageUrl = cardImageUrl;
        }

        public String getCategory() {
            return mCategory;
        }

        public void setCategory(String category) {
            mCategory = category;
        }

        public URI getBackgroundImageURI() {
            try {
                return new URI(getBackgroundImageUrl());
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeStringArray(new String[] {mId,
                    mTitle,
                    mDescription,
                    mBgImageUrl,
                    mCardImageUrl,
                    mVideoUrl,
                    mStudio,
                    mCategory});
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(200);
            sb.append("Movie{");
            sb.append("mId=" + mId);
            sb.append(", mTitle='" + mTitle + '\'');
            sb.append(", mVideoUrl='" + mVideoUrl + '\'');
            sb.append(", backgroundImageUrl='" + mBgImageUrl + '\'');
            sb.append(", backgroundImageURI='" + getBackgroundImageURI().toString() + '\'');
            sb.append(", mCardImageUrl='" + mCardImageUrl + '\'');
            sb.append('}');
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
            public Movie createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
                return new Movie(in);
            }

            public Movie[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Movie[size];
            }
        };
    }
```

I found a blog while I was googling related to this type of customization. You can take a look of URL below:
    https://medium.com/building-for-android-tv

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to customize browse fragment ?

Comment: Can you please specify the code to customize the header fragment only?

Comment: You need to customize Raw Fragment and Header fragment. Also you need to make a custom frame layout, As I already shared. I think you need to do some more R&D.

Comment: Could you answer this question of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554485/how-to-write-a-custom-leanbacks-verticalgridview-in-android-tv

Comment: `BaseRowFragment ` is package-private class, it is impossible to implement (subclass) it outside it's package