# How to write a custom Leanbacks VerticalGridView in Android TV?

Tags: android, leanback

I want to implement a `Row` from the Details screen of the `Leanback` library into a customized screen. The row will be the one below. I have already implemented the `HorizontalGridView` and have managed to get the items to be shown.

[image: Sample Image]

My layout:

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
android:id="@+id/detail_related"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

My Java:

```
RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter = new SimilarAssetsAdapter();
mBinding.detailRelated.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The problem I am encountering is that I cannot focus on any of the items but the focus is on the whole `HorizontalGridView`. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this, use a `VerticalGridView` instead of a `HorizontalGridView`.

```
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.VerticalGridView
    android:id="@+id/detail_related"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

To set the `ArrayObjectAdapter` to the `VerticalGridView`, use an `ItemBridgeAdapter`.

```
ItemBridgeAdapter adapter = new ItemBridgeAdapter();
adapter.setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
adapter.setPresenter(new SinglePresenterSelector(new ListRowPresenter()));
mBinding.detailRelated.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: can you please explain, what is `mBinding` in your code?

Comment: mBinding is the DataBinding component for that particular layout where the above xml is placed.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is a custom one, make sure you add the following to your customized view to get focus:

```
setFocusable(true);
setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in custom view is you need to add the focus change listener in the java code.Add the focus listener inside the adapter to the root view of the adapter items.

Add focusable for the rootview in the oncreate of the adapter items.

```
yourView.setFocusable(true);      
yourView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

Then in the onBind add the focuschangeListener.

```
 yourRootView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        if(hasFocus){
           //focus gained
        }else {
          //focus lost
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put
`android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"`
in your `.xml` file

```xml
<android.support.v17.leanback.widget.HorizontalGridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"/>
```